# Can seem to find the correct package configuration with Flutter 2.0

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

So I've been trying to get my packages to match the online migration guide: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration

But no matter what I do I always get a dependency error. Could you explain to me what I'm doing wrong ?
My latest error is this one:

```
Because url_launcher >=5.5.2 <5.7.7 depends on url_launcher_platform_interface ^1.0.8 and url_launcher >=5.4.1 <5.5.2 depends on url_launcher_platform_interface ^1.0.4, url_launcher >=5.4.1 <5.7.7 requires url_launcher_platform_interface ^1.0.4.
And because url_launcher_platform_interface >=1.0.4 <1.0.5 depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.0, url_launcher >=5.4.1 <5.7.7 requires plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.0 or url_launcher_platform_interface ^1.0.5.
And because url_launcher >=5.7.7 <6.0.0-nullsafety depends on url_launcher_platform_interface ^1.0.9 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1, url_launcher >=5.4.1 <6.0.0-nullsafety requires plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.0.
Because cloud_firestore >=1.0.4 depends on cloud_firestore_platform_interface ^4.0.1 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, cloud_firestore >=1.0.4 requires plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0.
Thus, cloud_firestore >=1.0.4 is incompatible with url_launcher >=5.4.1 <6.0.0-nullsafety.
So, because XXXXX depends on both cloud_firestore ^1.0.5 and url_launcher ^5.5.1, version solving failed.
```

Here is my pubspec:

```
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0

  google_sign_in: ^5.0.2
  provider: ^5.0.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  flutter_statusbarcolor: ^0.2.3
  pull_to_refresh: ^1.6.5
  flutter_displaymode: ^0.1.1
  curl: ^1.0.0
  #  random_user: ^0.3.0
  share: ^2.0.1
  mailto: ^2.0.0
  pinput: ^1.2.0
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.5
  cloud_functions: ^1.0.3
  firebase_analytics:   ^8.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.0
  firebase_core: ^1.0.3
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.0.0
  firebase_database: ^7.0.0-dev.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^2.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^9.1.1
  firebase_performance: ^0.7.0
  firebase_remote_config: ^0.10.0-dev.0
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.3
dependency_overrides:
  http: ^0.13.1
  url_launcher: ^5.5.1`
```

Comment: try to upgrade `url_launcher: ^6.0.3` or downgrade `url_launcher: ^5.4.1`

Comment: @AL.Sharie hello what are you doing here hhhhhhh

Comment: you might also do it like this `url_launcher: `  and the dependency manager will try to choose the best compatible version

Comment: Thanks downgrading worked and thankfully it was the last dependency error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading URL launcher fixed my problem, thanks !